# LWC navigation to a tab is showing the 'Loading...' in place of tab name

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

When I click View All in the below custom LWC component, the below piece of code gets invoked. 
[image]

```
  @track tabName = 'Payments';
  navigateToViewAll() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: this.tabName,
            }
        });
    }
```

The tab shows 'Loading...' as tab name instead of the Payments. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: We use a special variant of markdown; please use the edit controls if you're not familiar with our formatting to make sure your question looks correct. See [Editing Help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more information.

Comment: Are you using sales or service console application?

Comment: Please pay attention to the formatting, as sfdcfox said. I fixed it for you here; if you continue to edit your question, please make sure the formatting is correct.

Comment: @manjit5190 - Sales. However, this tab is invoked from a custom component in case or Accounts record page.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Sure, Thanks for your feedback and support.

Comment: It is likely because you have opened it as a background tab. Once you bring it in focus or click on it it should take the correct name or else you may have to use lightning console toolkit and use those methods to get the name correcrly

Comment: @David Reed - Sure, Thanks for you help.

Comment: @manjit5190 - Even when the tab is active, it still shows Laoding... . It would be great if you can provide or guide with more details to fix this as am kind of a newbie in salesforce.

Comment: I will check that. It may take some time.

Comment: @manjit5190 -  Sure, Please take your time. Thanks!

Comment: @GomathiHariharan were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @jm.Yes, I am using workspace api instead of LWC navigate Mixin to open a subtab and rename the opened tb with a required label. I invoke the aura workspace api logic when the 'View All' is clicked in the LWC component.